# Error when starting mysql on Mac OS 10.5

Tags: mysql, macos

I had a problem with my MySQL installation here the other day. After doing everything I could think of to no avail, I decided to reinstall the whole thing.

I installed the package format of the installation from mysql.com, and ran the installer. It installed it right where it was before i uninstalled it: /usr/local/mysql.

So I try to do this:

```
sudo echo
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
```

And I get this in response:

```
[3] 505
mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/PB15.lan.err'.
mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/PB15.lan.pid ended
```

When I try to do: sudo mate /usr/local/mysql/data/PB15.lan.err, I get an empty document.

Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in the end was installing snow lepoard, giving me a fresh install, and everything just works again. Thanks to everyone who took the time to answer.

Erik

Comment: you call this a 'solution'?

Comment: Well it solved the problem I had, even though it didn't address the symptoms. After all a 'solution' is a means of solving a problem. I no longer have a problem. I think it's just as good as the most up voted answer here saying I should install MAMP, since it also essentially is a re-install.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't answering your question, but [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) is a great way to go when using MySQL on Mac OS X. Not only do you not have to worry about installing MySQL, but you can also easily move your MySQL setup between computers.

Steve

Comment: I don't see any reason for using anything other than the default setup Apple already offers. I have been using this for years, and am very happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL binary packages from mysql.com come with a preference pane for starting and stopping it. Why aren't you using these? Even if you have a good reason not to, try to use it just to see if it works.

Another thing to check is to make sure you are downloading the 32-bit version of MySQL unless you are on a 64-bit Mac. If you aren't sure, just try the 32-bit version anyway.

Comment: Where is this preference pane located in the installation? I'm sure I have downloaded the right version of mysql.

Comment: In the dmg that you downloaded there should be a MySQL.pref(pane?) or something along those lines.  Double click it and it will install the pane in your system preferences in the very bottom row.

Comment: I tried the pref pane approach, but nothing happens. It only says that the server is stopped. When I press 'start mysql server', I get prompted for the root password, I type it in but nothing happens. No error message, nothing.

Comment: Erik, what about the 32-bit vs 64-bit version?

Comment: @bjeanes, I already said that I'm sure I have installed the correct version.

Comment: Have you tried trashing the whole /usr/local/mysql folder and reinstalling from scratch?